# UITextField Not Responding UIScrollView Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

I Have a `UIScrollView` in my `ViewController` and ContentView in `UIScrollView`.
There are various other Views in the Content View to make understanding of the used `labels` and `textfields` more readable

[Here is a screen shot to help you understand the hierarchy of the `viewcontroller`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbBdu.png)

All the Constraints are set properly I can see the `views` as they are aligned in storyboard on all size of devices, userInteraction is enabled on all the `textFields` and `UIViews` (I triple checked) still I'm not able to edit text on the textfields that are not immediately visible on the screen when the view controller is launched.

i.e. If the first three `UItextFields` are visible when the `viewController` is launched (4.0" device) they can be edited or if the first Five `UItextFields` are visible when the `viewController` is launched (5.7" device) they can be edited while the rest do not respond to user interaction

I've checked if they are in any case are overlapped or not by changing the background color of all the `Labels`, `TextFields` and `Views`. Nothing is overlapping anything, all are where they should be.

Content Size is set for `scrollView` in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
[self.scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width, 1724)]; }
```

The Height 1724 will never change no matter the size of the device on which the code is running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check your contentview size or setbackground color for `scrollview` and `contentview`. Contenview size is not increasing i think.

Comment: @Piyush Mehta Did you get what I am saying?

Comment: Thanks for the fix. the content view had the constraint of height equal to superview thats why it wasn't working.

Comment: Yes I have faced the same. Welcome brother :-)